# How to use HashSet and LinkedHashSet in-conjunction with List<WebElement> using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, collections, webdriver

I have written below code using ArrayList & HashSet. but the hash set is not working as expected means it doesn't remove duplicate items. but the Hash Set won't allow duplication.

```
**HTML** code

<HTML>
        <BODY>
        <select id= 'WesInn'>
        <option value = 'idli'> IDLI</option>
        <option value = 'vada'> VADA</option>
        <option value = 'sambhar'> SAMBHAR</option>
        <option value = 'Manchurian'> MACHURIAN</option>
        <option value = 'idli'> IDLI</option>
        <option value = 'sambhar'> SAMBHAR</option>
        <option value = 'Tea'> TEA</option>
        </select>
        </body>
        </html>

public class Assgn_DropDownAsc {
    //static String text;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\New folder/Dropdown.html");

        List list = new ArrayList ();
        LinkedHashSet hs = new LinkedHashSet();
         Adding ArrayList elements to the HashSet
         //in order to remove the duplicate elements and 
         //to preserve the insertion order.

        hs.addAll(list);
        //System.out.println(hs);
        //Removing ArrayList elements
        hs.clear();
        System.out.println(hs);
        System.out.println(list);
        //Adding LinkedHashSet elements to the ArrayList
        hs.addAll(list);
        //System.out.println(alloptions.size());
        System.out.println(list);
}
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

[ IDLI
 VADA
 SAMBHAR
 MACHURIAN
 IDLI
 SAMBHAR
 TEA]

Comment: Which type of data you are storing in `List and HashSet` is it `String`? Also using `raw` types never recommend

Comment: actually, I'm trying to store List<webElement> as above mentioned code. I have created own html code. in that, I created the list box using Select class. I am trying to store list elements into an arrayList & HashSet  which can be used to avoid to print duplicate element in list (e.g. IDLI)

Comment: First of should learn how `Set` actually works. Set uses `hashCode()` and `equals()` in order to determine  the a element is duplicate or not. So you should take look on the `hashCode()` and `equals()` of `WebElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is the solution I got.

package qsp;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class DropdownAscen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\New folder/Dropdown.html");

        WebElement listbox = driver.findElement(By.id("WesInn"));

        Select sel = new Select(listbox);
        List<WebElement> alllist = sel.getOptions();
        int count = alllist.size();
        System.out.println(count);
        /*for(int i=count-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            System.out.println(alllist.get(i).getText());
        }*/
        //Set hs = new HashSet<>(); /we will use this when we don't allow duplicate but not maintain insertion order
        Set<String> hs = new TreeSet<>(); //we will use this to maintain duplication & sorting order

        for(int i =0; i<count;i++)
        {
            WebElement option = alllist.get(i);
            String txt = option.getText();
            hs.add(txt);
            //System.out.println(txt);
        }
        for(String sortedLst:hs)
        {
            System.out.println(sortedLst);
        }
    }}
```

**OUTPUT**

IDLI
 MACHURIAN
 SAMBHAR
 TEA
 VADA

Answer (score 1):

Your program is working fine if you are storing String you mentioned in the output, looks like you are printing list instead of hashSet -
Change `System.out.println(list);` to `System.out.println(hs);`

It matters only in case you are storing objects of a class, in that case you should have overridden the equals() and hashCode() method properly to use hashSet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\New folder/Dropdown.html");

         ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
         al.add("IDLI");
         al.add("VADA");
         al.add("SAMBHAR");
         al.add("MACHURIAN");
         al.add("IDLI");
         al.add("SAMBHAR");
         al.add("TEA");

         System.out.println("Array list : "+ al);

         LinkedHashSet hs = new LinkedHashSet();
         hs.addAll(al);

         System.out.println("hash set :" +hs);
    }
```

**Output :**

```
Array list : [IDLI, VADA, SAMBHAR, MACHURIAN, IDLI, SAMBHAR, TEA]
hash set :[IDLI, VADA, SAMBHAR, MACHURIAN, TEA]
```

Comment: What is the difference in logic?

Comment: @eduPeeth : No change, it is the explained demonstration.

Comment: @eduPeeth : True. take it easy. I am up for upvoting your answer though

Comment: @eduPeeth :  If that was the intention , then you could have commented a single line in question itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174594/discussion-between-edupeeth-and-cruisepandey).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples of how to use *HashSet* and *LinkedHashSet* with `List<WebElement>` using *selenium webdriver*:

### Java [HashSet](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashset) class

Java HashSet class is used to create a collection that uses a hash table for storage. It inherits the AbstractSet class and implements Set interface.

- The important points about Java HashSet class are:

  - HashSet stores the elements by using a mechanism called hashing.
  - HashSet contains unique elements only.
  - Difference between List and Set: List can contain duplicate elements whereas Set contains unique elements only.
- HashSet class declaration:

  ```
  public class HashSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> implements Set<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
  ```
- Example (within a Google Search Page):

  ```
  List <WebElement> my_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='srg']/div[@class='g']//h3/a"));
  HashSet<WebElement> values = new HashSet<>(my_list);
  for(WebElement value:values)
      System.out.println(value.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Selenium (software) - Wikipedia
  Introduction — Selenium Documentation
  Selenium Tutorial
  Selenium Testing for Enterprise End-to-End Tests - Tricentis
  Selenium - Web Browser Automation
  Free Selenium Tutorials - Guru99
  Downloads - Selenium
  Selenium IDE
  Selenium with Python — Selenium Python Bindings 2 documentation
  ```

### Java [LinkedHashSet](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-linkedhashset) class

Java LinkedHashSet class is a Hash table and Linked list implementation of the set interface. It inherits HashSet class and implements Set interface.

- The important points about Java HashSet class are:

  - Contains unique elements only like HashSet.
  - Provides all optional set operations, and permits null elements.
  - Maintains insertion order.
  - Hierarchy of LinkedHashSet class.
  - The LinkedHashSet class extends HashSet class which implements Set interface. The Set interface inherits Collection and interfaces in hierarchical order.
- LinkedHashSet class declaration:

  ```
  public class LinkedHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> implements Set<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
  ```
- Example (within a Google Search Page):

  ```
  List <WebElement> my_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='srg']/div[@class='g']//h3/a"));
  LinkedHashSet<WebElement> values = new LinkedHashSet<>(my_list);
  for(WebElement value:values)
      System.out.println(value.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Selenium - Web Browser Automation
  Selenium IDE
  Downloads - Selenium
  Introduction — Selenium Documentation
  Free Selenium Tutorials - Guru99
  Selenium (software) - Wikipedia
  Selenium with Python — Selenium Python Bindings 2 documentation
  Selenium Tutorial
  Selenium Testing for Enterprise End-to-End Tests - Tricentis
  ```

Comment: I have tried this with the help of above solution but still, i'm getting duplicate list of items.

Comment: WebElement listbox = driver.findElement(By.id("WesInn"));
   
  Select sel = new Select(listbox);
  List<WebElement> alllist = sel.getOptions();
  LinkedHashSet<WebElement> values = new LinkedHashSet<>(alllist);
  for (WebElement we : values) {
   String txt = we.getText();
   System.out.println(txt);

Comment: @DhananjayDeshpande Can you update the question with the relevant _HTML_, your current code and the output? I am sure the text within different `options` would be different.